# Passing context from child to parent template in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

How do I pass the context used on the child template TO the parent template it inherits from?

Example:

in views.py

```
def author(request, code):
    author = get_object_or_404(Author, code=code)
    books = Book.objects.filter(author_id=author.id)
    reviews = Review.objects.filter(author_id=author)

    return render(request, 'foo/author.html', {'author': author, 'books': books, 'reviews': reviews})
```

in author.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

in base.html

```
{% for book in books %}
    <ul>
        <li>{{ book.title }}</li>
        <li>{{ book.year_published }}</li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

This is for the navigation bar that's inside the parent template('base.html'). It changes depending on which author page you are on.

Comment: The variables in the context should already be available in `base.html`. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: they aren't. when I try to print, for example, the book.title in base.html, nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried printing books in your views?

Comment: Yes I have. It doesn't recognize the variable.

Comment: Can you include the `views.py` code?

Comment: @RodXavier edited.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new block for books in `child.html`. This `bookblock` on child.html should override the `bookblock` exists inside `base.html`

```
{% bookblock %}
{% for book in books %}
    <ul>
        <li>{{ book.title }}</li>
        <li>{{ book.year_published }}</li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %} 
{% endblock %}
```

`base.html`

Put the code related to `book` inside a block where block name must be same on both base and child templates.

```
{% bookblock %}
{% for book in books %}
    <ul>
        <li>{{ book.title }}</li>
        <li>{{ book.year_published }}</li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %} 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Does that mean anytime I have to create a context based navbar, I'll have to add a separate block? 

I mean, if the nav-bar had two contextual dropdowns -- one for books and one for reviews -- I have to add a new block for the reviews?

Comment: This approach will get the result needed but it is not ideal when it comes to code maintenance as you have to repeat this block in every html page where the nav needs to appear.